# display product's custom image in custom email

Tags: magento-1.9, database, email, image

Once Registered user upload custom image in [product view page](http://sbdev2.kidsdial.com:81/custom-apple-iphone-4.html#)  & click on custom button "save design" , we are sending an email to customer. its working fine.

we are saving **customer id, product name, custom image path** in custom table : **"my_designs"**

[image]

but issue is **Product image is not displaying in email.**

```
<?php echo Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($this->getProductId())->getName() ?>
<image src="<?php echo $this->getValue() ?>">
```

we have preview to see all emails in backend, in preview product's custom image is displaying. but in email its not displaying.

**side note** : we are sending Abandoned cart email after customer click on "add to cart", in that email we are successfully custom image with help of below code :

```
<table width="0" border="0" cellspacing="5" cellpadding="10">
<?php foreach ($this->getQuote()->getAllVisibleItems() as $item): ?>
<tr>
<td><img src="<?php echo $this->getImageUrl($item->getProduct(), 100) ?>"/></td>
<td valign="top">
    <p><a href="<?php echo $item->getProduct()->getProductUrl() ?>"><?php echo $item->getName() ?></a></p>
    <b><?php echo $this->getFormattedPrice($item->getPrice()) ?></b>
</td>
</tr>
<?php if ($this->getQuoteImage($item)): ?>
<tr>
    <td>Your Design : <img src="<?php echo $this->getQuoteImage($item) ?>" /></td>
</tr>
<?php endif ?>
<?php endforeach ?>
</table>
```

**Backend preview** :

[image]

Comment: what exactly you want?? make it bit clear

Comment: @GopalPatel updated question, please check once....

Comment: Can you add your current email preview and where you want to show custom image in current email

Comment: @JaiminSutariya i need to display custom image in any place in email..... please check preview image in question.

Comment: Please add your email sending code which you are using to send mail on save design. also add your email template code to review

Comment: @JaiminSutariya i am using only this code to send email : here product name is displaying in email, but image is not displaying : `<?php echo Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($this->getProductId())->getName() ?>
<image src="<?php echo $this->getValue() ?>">`

Comment: What do you see as image src value in your email when you receive?

Comment: @JaiminSutariya in email , only name is displaying,in preview when i tried inspect element , i saw this : http://prnt.sc/eowfhe

Comment: @JaiminSutariya if you upload image or text in [link](http://sbdev2.kidsdial.com:81/custom-apple-iphone-4.html) and click on `save design` , than you also recieve email within 5 min :

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/56081/discussion-between-jaimin-sutariya-and-baby-in-magento).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to update your email template code from,

```
<?php echo Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($this->getProductId(‌​))->getName() ?> <image src="<?php echo $this->getValue() ?>">
```

to

```
<?php echo Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($this->getProductId(‌​))->getName() ?><img src="<?php echo $this->getValue() ?>" alt="<?php echo Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($this->getProductId())->getName(); ?>" />
```

As There is no HTML tag with name `image`, you need to use `img` tag.